# ForeignKey inconsistently working across Sites

Tags: python, django

I have a parent BlogPost on one Site and a number of children ('clones') BlogPosts on other Sites.

```
class BlogPost(models.Model):
    clone_source = models.ForeignKey(
        "self",
        related_name='clones',
    )
```

If I'm looking at a Child `active_post` and I run

```
parent = active_post.clone_source
siblings = parent.clones.all()
```

I correctly get all the children as expected.

However, if I'm on the Parent as `active_post`,

`active_post.clones.all()`

returns an empty list.  It's the same code, no?

Also,
`children = BlogPost.all_sites.filter(clone_source=active_post)`

returns all the children correctly.  What's the difference?

Comment: Does BlogPost extend `object`, or does it extend `models.Model` ?

Comment: sorry, `models.Model`.  Fixed